# Next-Auth with Prisma, using Google authentication and creating Roles in the Sign Up

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-oauth, prisma, next-auth

I'm using Next.JS for front-end, Next-Auth to authentication and Prisma as my ORM.

I have a problem when creating a user because I have some roles that the user can choose: "Events", "Brand" or "Athlete".
He chooses them when creating an account, but the problem is, when the user creates the account using Google authentication, I cannot use the role information, the account is created but the Role information is discarded.

I want to use this Role information when creating with Google Or Facebook auth (I believe is the same way for both).

**Front-End:**

[image: Front-end]

**Here is the code to Next-Auth:**

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,

      profile(profile, token) {
        console.log('TOKEN', token)
        return {
          ...profile,
          id: profile.sub,
          role: token.role,
        }
      },
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: 'Email',
          type: 'email',
          placeholder: 'exemplo@exemplo.com',
        },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },

      async authorize(credentials) {
        console.log('CREDENTIALS: ', credentials)
        // check to see if email and password is there
        if (credentials?.email === '' || credentials?.password === '') {
          throw new NextResponse('Please enter an email and password', {
            status: 400,
          })
        }

        // check to see if user exists
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials?.email,
          },
        })

        // if no user was found
        if (!user || !user?.password) {
          throw new NextResponse('No email found', {
            status: 400,
          })
        }

        // check to see if password matches
        await bcrypt
          .compare(credentials?.password as string, user.password)
          .then((passwordMatchBool) => {
            // if password does not match
            if (!passwordMatchBool) {
              throw new NextResponse('Incorrect password', {
                status: 400,
              })
            }
          })

        return user
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/account/login',
    newUser: '/account/experience-form',
    error: '/account/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async redirect() {
      return '/'
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return { ...token, ...user }
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token
      return session
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
}
```

**And for the front-end button:**

```
<Button
            className="border-1 flex w-full justify-start border-gray-600 bg-white py-6 font-semibold text-black hover:bg-gray-100"
            onClick={() => signIn('google')}
          >
```

I saw a lot of things in the internet but no one is passing the Role value in the creation, they define the role as "Google User" or "Email User", things like that, where they pass statically the value

I tried some things like change the profile in the AuthOptions, I tried to pass the value to google auth, but nothing works.

Comment: What about creating a user first (without any role selection) and after the user has been registered successfully, he is asked for his role as the second independent step? I think such a multi-level registration process is quite convenient, e.g. when you have to add additional information like your name, etc, this is commonly an extra step after registration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save the Role in a global context, when the user is created first time, the Next-Auth call the page newUser, to explain better:

```
 pages: {
    signIn: '/account/login',
    newUser: '/account/experience-form',
    error: '/account/login',
  },
```

In this part of the code, you call /account/experience-form in newUser, in this page you can make a validation, if the user login by provider, you update the user Role, if were by email and password you do nothing

Comment: I created this page to do some thing like that, but it looks like not the correct way, I think another way is passing in the callback function the role.